# Multiple relationships to UserId in one table

Tags: model-view-controller, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, visual-studio-2013, relationships

I have a UserProfile with a UserId. I need to create a relationship to a table Scorecards where there are multiple columns that need to have a relationship with UserId. They are ScorerId, CreatedById, AgentId, ModifiedById, PublishedById ....

I am unsure of how this would be done via code first approach with mvc 4 and entity 5?

Any Help would be appreciated.

```
public class ScorecardsModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ScorecardId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Agent ID")]
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Agent Name")]
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Scorer")]
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Call")]
    public int CallNum { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Call Date/Time")]
    public DateTime? CallDateTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Procedural Score")]
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int ProceduralScore { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Soft Skills Score")]
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int SoftSkillsScore { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Total Score")]
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int TotalScore { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Modified { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Modified By")]
    public int ModifiedById { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Modified On")]
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Completed By")]
    public int CompletedById { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Completed On")]
    public DateTime? CompletedOn { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Published By")]
    public int PublishedById { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Published On")]
    public DateTime? PublishedOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Template")]
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
```

And UserProfile:

```
 public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following link [Relationships in EF5 - Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258314/both-one-to-one-and-one-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-5-code-first). It might be what you are looking for.

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table) if you get stuck.

And lastly in this [ASP Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1803190.aspx?Two+foreign+keys+to+same+table+with+EF), is some more information