# Both One-to-Zero/One and One-to-Many relation in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, one-to-many, one-to-one

I google up hell lot but could not get it completely, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258314/both-one-to-one-and-one-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-5-code-first) I found little useful info but not to success. Below is my question,

I have below classes and need a way to specify the relation in entity model.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int? HomeAddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual Address HomeAddress{ get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; } 

    // other properties
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Requirement is each User has many addresses and each address is associated with one User(one-to-many). 
One of the address is Home Address and hence the User has HomeAddres(optional). HomeAddressId is FK (nullable) to Address table. How do I define this relation in entity model code first preferably in Fluent API method?

Comment: if you made copy your code and paste here.y you have wrong definition User member of Adress. I changed it. 
and this code should work.additional you could change your model. Addresses  collect all address. you can seperate adress by type as AddresType member of Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to show code my easy way.

```
   public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int? HomeAddressId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public Address HomeAddress { 
           get {
                if(Addresses != null)
                   return Addresses.FirstOrDefault(p=> p.AddressType.Home);
                return null;
           }
        }
    }
    public enum AddressType
    {
        Unknown,
        Home,
        Office
    }
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; } 
    public AddressType AddressType {get; set; }

    // other properties
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Second fluent.

```
public class User
{
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public virtual Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
     public virtual int? HomeAddressId { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Address> OfficeAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
     public int AddressId { get; set; }
     public string AddressLine1 { get; set; } 
}

public class UserMap : MapEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
     public UserMap ()
     {
        //Other definitions PK etc...

        this.HasOptional(o => o.HomeAddress)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.HomeAddressId);

        this.HasMany(t => t.OfficeAddresses)
          .WithMany()
          .Map(m =>
          {
              m.ToTable("UserOfficeAddresses");
              m.MapLeftKey("AddressId");
              m.MapRightKey("UserId");
          });
     }
}
//and define Address Configurations.. MapEntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
```

Comment: possibly this will resolve the question but not as per my approach, I don't want to add an extra AddressType field on Address here. The question is to have HomeAddressId on User object and use it.

Comment: i see. it just only simple and easy solution. other akternatives you should use fluent api for define relations. I will try to awswer it. ;)

Comment: second what you ask.